# How do I upload a file to a specific folder using php

Tags: php

I tried uploading and renaming an image file with php, but he doesn't move the file to the folder I want it in. Can someone tell me whats wrong with the code?

```
        $filename = $_POST["avatar"];
    $expl = explode('.', $filename);
    $file_basename = $user; // give new name
    $file_ext = $expl[1]; // get file extention
    $filesize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
    $allowed_file_types = array('gif', 'jpg', 'pjpg', 'png');
    $target_dir = "images/avatars/";
    $newfilename = $file_basename . '.' . $file_ext;
    $target_file = $target_dir . $newfilename;

    if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 2000000000)) {
        if (file_exists($target_dir . $newfilename)) {
            echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $target_dir);
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
            } else {
                $avaq = "UPDATE portfoliotext SET avatar = '$newfilename'";
                $resava = mysqli_query($conn, $avaq);
                echo "File uploaded successfully.";
            }
        }
    } elseif ($filesize > 2000000000) {
        echo "The file you are trying to upload is too large.";
    } else {
        echo "Only these file typs are allowed for upload: " . implode(', ', $allowed_file_types);
    }
} else {
    echo "Invalid file";
}
```

Comment: 1: check you've got the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute set. 2: check the directory ownership and permissions (do **not** 777) 2: validating on file extension is almost entirely pointless and your script will reject images like *my.lovely.horse.jpg*

Comment: maybe that as well ^^

Answer (score 0):

I received a few errors with the extra closing bracket and the extra `else` clause.

Maybe try this:

```
$filename = $_POST["avatar"];
$expl = explode('.', $filename);
$file_basename = $user; // give new name
$file_ext = $expl[1]; // get file extention
$filesize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
$allowed_file_types = array('gif', 'jpg', 'pjpg', 'png');
$target_dir = "images/avatars/";
$newfilename = $file_basename . '.' . $file_ext;
$target_file = $target_dir . $newfilename;

if (in_array($file_ext, $allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 2000000000)) {
    if (file_exists($target_dir . $newfilename)) {
        echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $target_dir);
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        } else {
            $avaq = "UPDATE portfoliotext SET avatar = '$newfilename'";
            $resava = mysqli_query($conn, $avaq);
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";
        }
    }
} elseif ($filesize > 2000000000) {
    echo "The file you are trying to upload is too large.";
} else {
    echo "Only these file typs are allowed for upload: " . implode(', ', $allowed_file_types);
}
```